# in Flash AS2 ok, but in AS3 error message: expecting right paren before eq

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I use Flash Professional CC 2015 with AS3. When opening the flashfile which I wrote using AS2 before, it says it must convert some stuff into AS3. I take it that is done automatically. But for this there are two identical error messages

**"error message: expecting right paren before eq"**, refering to the second column. It worked perfectly in AS2, how to change so it works in AS3? I played around with it, but could not solve it.

In Flash AS2 I used this:

```
cat1_mc.onEnterFrame = function(){
    if((catlocated eq "Task 1 completed!") & (catfoodlocated eq "Task 2   completed!")){
        door_btn._visible = true;
        door_btn.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in AS. I was also wondering, why here eq means equal, but in other commands, you use "=", not "eq". Anyways

Comment: `eq` is wrong there, use `=`, that is what the error says

Comment: oops, use  `==` instead of `eq` `eq` is NOT used in actionscript to define equality testing, `==` is the operator for equality testing

Comment: @NikosM. In reality, the `eq` was used in AS1 and AS2 to compare strings but was deprecated since Flash Player 5 ...

Comment: @akmozo, ok, AS1 is not used, AS2 supported the `==` operator and AS3 as well, no need to use `eq` from AS1 (as it seems)

Comment: After re-reading your question, I see that you want to convert your AS2 code to AS3, and that even if that error was avoided you have a lot of things that you should do to get an AS3 working code, that's why I advise you to take a look on the migration part at this [page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) ... I removed my answer because it's useless in that case ...

Comment: Also for future handling of conditionals see http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3conditionals/

Answer (score 2):

a logical AND requires **`&&`** and not `&`

and logical EQUALS requires **`==`** and not `eq`

you also don't need the inner brackets, but that's not really an error

```
cat1_mc.onEnterFrame = function(){
    if(catlocated == "Task 1 completed!" && catfoodlocated == "Task 2   completed!"){
        door_btn._visible = true;
        door_btn.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

> I am a beginner in AS. I was also wondering, why here eq means equal, but in other commands, you use "=", not "eq"

the concept of `equals` has two meanings in any programming or scripting language (AFAIK).

- Asignemnt: `=`, which is can be read as `make x equal 15`
- Equality: `==`,`eq`, which checks equality `does x equal 15?` and returns true or false

The reason (IMO) that some languages use `eq`, `neq`, `lt` etc. instead of `==`,`!=`,`<` etc. is to make it more friendly for beginners to understand. As programmers became more demanding of ActionScript capabilities, the language became more robust, and dropped some of these conventions. When dealing with advanced concepts such as event handlers and garbage collection in AS3, the entry barrier goes a little higher.

Comment: I've put (and removed) an answer as yours exactly because after verifying OP's question, I think that he is trying to convert his AS2 code to AS3, so our answers are useless in that case because his current AS2 code is fine (`eq` and `&` work fine for an AS2 code) ...